# Netezza SQL + Correlated Subquery = ERROR: (2) This form of correlated query is not supported - consider rewriting

Tags: sql, netezza

I need to match a date from one table based on the date from another table. Easy? Well. . . each date is dependent on the other one and TABLE A = 202212 and TABLE B = 2022-12-30 (last business day of the month). Here's what I have but Netezza isn't accepting it. The subquery on its own does work. Can anyone help me rewite?

Thanks

```
Select a.id, a.dt
from table A,
     Table B
where a.id = b.id
  and a.dt = (select distinct string_to_int(to_char(to_date(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMM'), 10)
              from table C 
              where last_bus_day = 1 
                and mth = cast(substr(a.dt, 5, 2) as integer)
                and yr = substr(a.dt, 1, 4) );
```

Comment: I'd A) JOIN the subquery. B) If A doesn't work, JOIN Table C.